# Spring Integration is hanging WebSphere Liberty thread

Tags: spring, websphere, spring-integration, websphere-liberty

I have a Spring + Spring Integration + Hibernate WebApp deployed in a WebSphere Liberty Application Server.

Sometimes, when i try to Stop the application, the server goes down.

I see this in the Log:

```
[12/16/15 9:27:27:146 CET] 00000096 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [CATAPP#web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]:.Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'IntegrationContext'
[12/16/15 9:39:36:112 CET] 000000f1 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "Default : 2" (00000096) has been active for 729034 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
```

And there is no more info. I need to restart the WebSphere node to start the application again.

I know it's difficult, but somebody knows what may be the problem ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit this situation, take a thread dump (jstack, jvisualvm etc) and look to see what the thread is doing. For example, it might be reading from a socket with a long (or no) timeout. If you can't figure it out, post the thread dump someplace.